# Doing multiple XMLHttpRequest from different url

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest to get data from two different localhost ports. It will run the request as soon as the page loaded. And I will run a function as soon as it finish getting the data from the 2 ports. But so far, only can get the data from local port 1000. I have check the ports already but no problem. The problem must have been the javascript.

js:

```
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://localhost:1000/data1";
  var info1;
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          info1 = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  var xmlhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url1 = "http://localhost:2000/data2";
  var info2;
  xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp1.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp1.status == 200) {
          info2 = jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp1.responseText);
          reload(info1, info2);
      }
  }
  xmlhttp1.open("GET", url1, true);
  xmlhttp1.send();

  function reload(info1, info2) {
      alert("success");
      // processing the data
  }
```

Is it that something wrong with the javascript?

Comment: What does the Console in your Developer Tools say?

Comment: Visual studio uses ie7 as browser right? Is it that it can't get data from 2 different local ports?

Comment: I have no idea what VS uses internally, but I wouldn't make IE7 a target platform. It's ancient, buggy and unsupported by Microsoft. It would explain why you can't get cross-origin data though: http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors

Comment: Ok. I've try another approach which is switching to Chromium using CefSharp. This is my new topic:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489883/ways-to-get-data-from-localhost-port-using-cefsharp. But I still have problem receving the data. Any other suggestion I can use for my application?